# Installation PHOENIX on linux mint (Error: OpenSSL)

Tags: installation, openssl, elixir, phoenix-framework, linux-mint

I have problems to install phoenix on my linux mint (18.3). Can anybody help me?

I have installed erlang (20) and elixir (1.6.3) with the the installation routine from [phoenixframework](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/installation.html#content).

But when I came to command `$ mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez` to install phoenix, I get the error:

> [error] Unable to load crypto library. Failed with error:
>   ":load_failed, Failed to load NIF library
>   /usr/lib/erlang/lib/crypto-4.2.1/priv/lib/crypto: 'libcrypto.so.1.0.2:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'" OpenSSL
>   might not be installed on this system.

I looked in the synaptic-package-manager from my linux and see that "libssl1.0.0" is already installed. (I also tried to install from local path like it is described, but the problem is the same at the end.)

Can anybody help?

Comment: It looks like it needs the dev package. Try installing `libssl1.0-dev` or `libssl-dev`.

Comment: I installed `libssl-dev`. (`libssl1.0-dev` not found). But I have the same problem after it.

Comment: Most linux distros fragment erlang packages. In the projects I work with we usually recommend installing `esl-erlang` from erlang solutions, which come with all the features we need. In your case however I think `erlang-crypto` may suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.2
```

or [manual package installed](https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2l-2+deb9u2_amd64.deb.html). Then...

```
sudo apt-get install erlang-crypto
```

Then I could create my first project without errors:

```
mix phx.new hello
```

Thanks @bla